# How to close connections in Akka-stream Tcp server?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

The expected behavior of close() in our akka-streams based Tcp server is that the client should immediately see SocketException and none of the messages published after the exception should be delivered to server. However, the last message sent before the exception must be delivered. All new clients should encounter ConnectException.

Unable to decipher the paragraph about "Closing connections" on [akka-streams 1.0 docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/scala/stream-io.html) we are using an implementation close() as follows for a Tcp Server:

```
  val serverSource: Promise[ByteString] = Promise[ByteString]()

  var serverBindingOption: Option[Tcp.ServerBinding] = None

  def bind(address: String, port: Int, target: ActorRef, maxInFlight: Int)
    (implicit system: ActorSystem, actorMaterializer: ActorMaterializer): Future[SyslogStreamServer] = {
    implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher
    val sink = Sink.foreach {
      conn: Tcp.IncomingConnection =>
        val targetSubscriber = ActorSubscriber[Message](system.actorOf(Props(new TargetSubscriber(target, maxInFlight))))

        val targetSink = Flow[ByteString]
          .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), maximumFrameLength = MaxFrameLength, allowTruncation = true))
          .map(raw ⇒ Message(raw))
          .to(Sink(targetSubscriber))

        conn.flow.to(targetSink).runWith(Source(serverSource.future).drop(1)) // drop the last one for no response
    }

    for {
      serverBinding ← Tcp().bind(address, port).to(sink).run()
    } yield {
      serverBindingOption = Some(serverBinding)
      new SyslogStreamServer
    }
  }

  def close()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Unit] = {
    serverSource.success(ByteString.empty) // dummy value to be dropped above
    serverBindingOption match {
      case Some(serverBinding) ⇒ serverBinding.unbind()
      case None ⇒ Future[Unit] {}
    }
  }
```

Is this a good way to close the server ? (for deployments etc.)

If someone could review and comment on the validity of the above implementation of close(). We are trying to prove or, disprove ourselves whether this code meets all the requirements and wondering if we should succeed the flow's source first or, unbind the serverBinding first ? Any review / criticism is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance !